# Why won't my Projection nor my Camera View work in my OpenGL

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

So I've went through the android tutorial many times, and I have gone through a lot of research and test and trial, but I still can't get a grip on drawing shapes the way I want them to be drawn. I decided to start another new openGL project that is a completely copy and paste project of the android tutorial, but when it comes to the projection and camera view, I have a problem. I understand how the following code works:

```
Matrix.setLookAtM(mViewMatrix, 0, 0, 0, -5, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
Matrix.frustumM(mProjectionMatrix, 0, -ratio, ratio, -3, 3, 2, 10);
Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjectionMatrix, 0, mViewMatrix, 0);
```

And I know changing one of these 3 methods should basically change the orientation of the shape in some kind of way. So, I started to play around with these values, trying every possibility I can, yet the image of the triangle stays exactly the same. So I researched more, and figured out that the shader code was wrong in the tutorial, and should look more like(where uMVPMatrix was added):

```
     private final String vertexShaderCode =
            "attribute vec4 vPosition;" +"attribute vec4 uMVPMatrix;"+
            "void main() {" +
            "  gl_Position =vPosition*uMVPMatrix;" +
            "}";
```

So, I applied the uMVPMatrix and now the triangle is gone. So, I did more research and figured out that most people do uMVPMatrix*vPosition, so I did this as well, and the triangle is still gone. I'd like to know why my projection and camera view aren't working the way I expect them too, and I would also love to have a piece of code that works exactly like what's expected in the android tutorials, so that I can have an example code to always refer back too.

Here's my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private GLSurfaceView mGLView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


     mGLView = new MyGLSurfaceView(this);
        setContentView(mGLView);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

//---------------------Open Gl Code-------------------------------------------------------------------

```
class MyGLSurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView {

    public MyGLSurfaceView(Context context){
        super(context);

        setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
        setRenderer(new MyGLRenderer());
        setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);
    }
}

Triangle mTriangle;
float [] mViewMatrix=new float[16];
float [] mMVPMatrix=new float[16];
float [] mProjectionMatrix=new float[16];
float [] mViewMatrix2=new float[16];
float [] mMVPMatrix2=new float[16];

public class MyGLRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {

    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 unused, EGLConfig config) {
        GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

        mTriangle = new Triangle();

    }

    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 unused) {
        GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        Matrix.setLookAtM(mViewMatrix, 0, 0, 0, -3, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjectionMatrix, 0, mViewMatrix, 0);

        mTriangle.draw(mMVPMatrix);
    }

    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 unused, int width, int height) {
        GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

        float ratio = (float) width / height;
        Matrix.frustumM(mProjectionMatrix, 0, -ratio, ratio, -3, 3, 2, 7);
    }
}
////////////////////Triangle//////////////////////////////////////////////////////


public class Triangle {

    private FloatBuffer vertexBuffer, colorBuff;
    static final int COORDS_PER_VERTEX = 3;
    float triangleCoords[] = {   // in counterclockwise order:
            0.0f,  0.622008459f, 0.0f, // top
            -0.5f, -0.311004243f, 0.0f, // bottom left
             0.5f, -0.311004243f, 0.0f  // bottom right
    };

    float color[] = { 0.63671875f, 0.76953125f, 0.22265625f, 1.0f};
    int mProgram;

    public Triangle() {
        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(
                triangleCoords.length * 4);
        bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        vertexBuffer = bb.asFloatBuffer();
        vertexBuffer.put(triangleCoords);
        vertexBuffer.position(0);


        int vertexShader = loadShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertexShaderCode);
        int fragmentShader = loadShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentShaderCode);

        mProgram = GLES20.glCreateProgram();             // create empty OpenGL ES Program
        GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, vertexShader);   // add the vertex shader to program
        GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, fragmentShader); // add the fragment shader to program
        GLES20.glLinkProgram(mProgram);                  // creates OpenGL ES program executables
    }

    private final String vertexShaderCode =
            "attribute vec4 vPosition;" +"attribute vec4 uMVPMatrix;"+
            "void main() {" +
            "  gl_Position =vPosition*uMVPMatrix;" +
            "}";

        private final String fragmentShaderCode =
            "precision mediump float;" +
            "uniform vec4 vColor;" +
            "void main() {" +
            "  gl_FragColor = vColor;" +
            "}";

        public int loadShader(int type, String shaderCode){

            // create a vertex shader type (GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
            // or a fragment shader type (GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)
            int shader = GLES20.glCreateShader(type);

            // add the source code to the shader and compile it
            GLES20.glShaderSource(shader, shaderCode);
            GLES20.glCompileShader(shader);

            return shader;
        }

        static final int vertexStride = COORDS_PER_VERTEX * 4;
        static final int vertexCount = 3;

        public void draw(float [] mvpMatrix) {
            GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram);
            int mPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "vPosition");
            GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
            GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, COORDS_PER_VERTEX,
                                         GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
                                         vertexStride, vertexBuffer);
            int mColorHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "vColor");
            GLES20.glUniform4fv(mColorHandle, 1, color, 0);
            int mMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "uMVPMatrix");
            GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mvpMatrix, 0);
            GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertexCount);
            GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
        }


}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you declare `uMVPMatrix` in your shader does not match the way it is used. You declare it as a `vec4` attribute, while you set it as a matrix uniform. So the declaration in the vertex shader should be:

```
uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;
```

It depends on how your matrices are set up, but it's also somewhat unusual in GLSL shaders to multiply your vectors from the left. I haven't used the matrix utility functions in Android, but from the documentation I suspect that you will need to multiply the vectors from the right:

```
gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * vPosition;
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this works to perfection. I've probably made 4 different Open GL projects each with disfigured shapes because I never had an example to go on.